# how to make responsive menu div which scrolls when screen resizes

Tags: responsive-design, yui-pure-css

I am using purecss to make a responsive website. In my page I have a HEADER and FOOTER; both of them are fixed and in between them I have CONTENT which has left vertical menu and the right side has some content.

Now what I want to achieve is when any resizing happens then my left side menu should have a scroll bar like of its own and the content in the right should also have one. Plus the menu div should not go mix with the footer or the header.

I am not very sure but do I need to use mobile-webkits to resolve this issue.

I have found something to help:
http://filamentgroup.github.io/Overthrow/examples/2-column/

Is this the only way or are there any other libraries which can help me in this?

Comment: What does your code look like now? What have you tried? We can answer specific questions, but we can't do a layout/design for you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5Ktt/

Answer (score 0):

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5Ktt/4/)**

Basically, I added in JQuery with functions to change the height of the left hand menu on resize. That, combined with the overflow from Y forces it to have scroll bars.

Onload:

```
$(function() {
var menuWrapper = $("#menu");
var height = $(window).height() - $("#header").height() - $("#footer").height();
menuWrapper.css("height", height);
});
```

On Resize:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
var menuWrapper = $("#menu");
var height = $(window).height() - $("#header").height() - $("#footer").height();
menuWrapper.css("height", height);
});
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```